# Setting Programs on Redhat5 Startup

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a Redhat 5 OS, a dual monitor setup, and two workspace. When the machine reboots, I want to set the following:

On workspace 1,

```
 * run the thunderbird-client on the left monitor.
 * run 3 terminal clients on the right monitor.
```

On workspace 2,

```
 * run firefox on the right monitor.
```

Can someone point me as to where I can set these settings? I am sure there is a way since when my machine boots up, couple of terminal clients pops up, my irc chat client pops up as well. I do not know how I did this before.

Comment: Have these running when you log out and save your session.

Answer (score 0):

You could try **Devil's Pie** (yum install devilspie)

It's a tool for creating rules that will bind specific actions to applications as they are launched (i.e. setting workspace, position, transparency, etc...).

I found some doc here: http://www.foosel.org/linux/devilspie and here: http://live.gnome.org/DevilsPie

Of course, saving your workspace on logout can help too (**System** > **Preferences** > **More Preferences** > **Sessions**, then check "**Automatically save changes to session**").

Once you have setup your application rules, you could write a simple Bash script to start them all in sequence, and add that script to the Startup programs in the sessions preferences.